# For each div with same class do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some divs with same class. Inside this divs i added another div to put an ad.
Now i am trying to hide the ad div if the width of the div that holds my ad div is equal to 366px;

I tried the code bellow but it hides only my first ad div..

Example:

```
<div class="masterdiv">
<div id="myaddiv"></div>
</div>

<div class="masterdiv">
<div id="myaddiv"></div>
</div>

<div class="masterdiv">
<div id="myaddiv"></div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is:

```
var adwidth = $(".masterdiv").width();
if (adwidth == 366){
$('#myaddiv').hide();   
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you also have multiple `id`'s. they need to be unique

Comment: id is must be unique. otherwise you can use class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `var adwidth = $(".masterdiv").width();` only returns the first value. The answer is in your title, you need to use each. Another issue is ids are SINGULAR, so you need to use a class

**Using each:**

```
$(".masterdiv").each( function() {
    var elem = $(this);
    var width = elem.width();  
    if (width == 366){
        elem.find('.myaddiv').hide(); //use a class since only one element can have an id   
    }
});
```

**Using filter:**

```
$(".masterdiv").filter( function() {
    return ($(this).width() == 366);   
}).find('.myaddiv').hide();
```

**The updated HTML:**

```
<div class="masterdiv">
    <div class="myaddiv"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: any example please? Thank you! I tried this $('.masterdiv').each(function() {
my rest code
)}; Without luck

Answer (score 1):

you should not use duplicate ids.use:

```
$('div .masterdiv').each(function(){
  if($(this).width()==366){
   $(this).find('div').hide();
}});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$('.masterdiv').each(function(){
   if($(this).width()==386){
       $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is only doing the first div because you are using id's instead of classes. Since there can only be one id per page javascript stops after matching the first one. change to classes and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".masterdiv").each(function(){
    var current = $(this);
    if(current.width() == 366) {
        current.hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using same id's for different divs

Instead of id, give class name

```
<div class="masterdiv">
        <div class="myaddiv">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="masterdiv">
        <div class="myaddiv">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="masterdiv">
        <div class="myaddiv">
        </div>
    </div>


$(document).ready(function () {
        var adwidth = $(".masterdiv");
        for (i = 0; i < adwidth.length; i++) {
            if ($(adwidth[0]).attr("width") == 366) {
                $(this).find('.myaddiv').hide()
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change in this way:

```
 $('#myaddiv', '.masterdiv').each(function() {
      var width = $(this).width();
      (width > 366) ? $(this).hide() : 0;    
 });
```

You can try on this [live **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ALy3/1/)